# c++ assign to pointer a pointer to constant

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I have the following code:

```
class B{
    /*
    ...
    */
};
class A{
    B** elements;
    public:
        A operator+=(const B& b){
            // this->elements[0] = &b;

        }
        A(int number){
            this->elements = new B*[number];
        }
    /*
    ...
    */
};

int main(){
    A a(10);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is that the += operator should add the B object(operator's right side) to the A object's elements member.
So let's say I modify main to :

```
int main{
    A a(10);
    B b();
    a += b;
}
```

After this a.elements[0] should be the b object.
I commented a line which is not working,but shows what I want.Uncommenting it gives the following error: invalid conversion from const B* to B*

The real code is much longer of course, it's enough if you show me how to make the += operator always assign the B object to A.elements[0], then I can edit my code as neccessary.

Thanks

Comment: Make the argument *not* constant? Or don't store pointers but objects? And don't use a pointer to pointer for the collection but a proper container like `std::vector`?

Comment: You got failure in a process of storing dangling pointer, I do not think that fixing this particular problem would help you. You need to rethink your design. Or better use container, that created by somebody, who knows how language works.

Comment: It looks like you actually want `std::vector<B>`.

Answer (score 3):

Focusing your issue, a `B*` is not a `B const*`: on the first you are allowed to call methods which are not `const`, while this is not true for the latter.

And the compiler is complaining about this: you declare an array of pointers to modifiable `B`s but then you try to store a pointer to an unmodifiable `B` inside it. So if you merely want to fix this problem you can decide for example to store unmodifiable Bs:

```
  B const** elements;
public:
 A& operator+=(const B& b) {
    this->elements[0] = &b;
    return *this;
  }

  A(int number) {
    this->elements = new B const*[number];
  }
```

But there are serious issues in your code:

- you are taking the address of a `const B&` but where is this B coming from? It could have automatic storage and become an invalid pointer somewhere in the future
- there is no way to know who is owning the pointer to `B` objects so who is responsible of releasing it.

It's C++, you have `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::vector`, just trying to do things as you would do them in C without even attempting to make them safe and secure doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have some serious issues with your design.

```
    A operator+=(const B& b){
        // this->elements[0] = &b;
```

The idea here is to insert b into your collection, but your collection is little more than a pointer to some (unknown length) amount of raw memory.  You do not have a way to know if elements[x] exists in order to store &b.  For that matter, you don't know if elements exists at all.  You will need more bookkeeping to store lengths.

But worse, you pass a reference to a const B and take its address, storing that pointer in your collection.  What if the argument is a reference bound to a temporary?  (Rvalues *can* bind to const lvalue references).  In that case, the moment you've finished inserting the pointer into your collection the object it points to is destroyed.

That is assuming you work around your const-incorrectness, as you take a reference to a const b, take its address, and hope that it points to a non-const B.  It doesn't.  Casting it away can result in undefined behavior if b really points to an actually const object (and the non-const interface of b is used through your pointer.)

Your grow function leaks memory and loses the old elements.  Yes, it's pseudocode but too far from anything real to base ideas on.

There is a lot of really dangerous ideas in just a few lines.  Here are suggestions:

- do not store raw pointers
- even more strongly, do not store pointers obtained from reference arguments
- make lifetime management easy; use smart pointers to show who owns the memory of passed-in objects
- maintain const correctness.  If you take (smart) pointers to const objects, store them as (smart) pointers to const objects.
- when you resize allocations allocations, worry about what happens to the old objects and memory.  Containers help reduce this effort.
- use container classes instead of managing raw memory yourself and many of your problems vanish (but not the lifetime management issue of the arguments.)